# Leading to "insecure" warning page only if I use the external IP of the VM (but otherwise worked properly)

Tags: nginx, virtual-machines, https

Here is the current situation of my deployed web app, which I want to be compatible with SSL and already put my certificate and its key on the virtual machine (Ubuntu with nginx):

- When I typed in the search bar my external IP address of the VM with https (e.g. `https://108.251.231.192`), it got me to the error page showing it is "insecure" and the malicious attacker can steal your password from the external IP address.
- However, when I tried to remove the `s` from `https`, for example `http://108.251.231.192`, the page is redirected to my actual domain with `https`, which is like `https://example.com` and have no problem.
- When I tried to type in `http://example.com`, it automatically is redirected to `https://example.com` without any problems. Typing in `https://example.com` got me my app for sure.

So my question is, why does the first one, that using the external IP address with `https` (not `http`), got me to the error page with the insecure warning? Does it potentially cause any problem if I keep it untouched, or what should I do to remove the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your certificate probably doesn't have a CN matching your IP address.

Establishing a "secure" HTTPS connection implies your certificate CN matching the host requested.

Comment: Hmmm... sorry for being late to respond but I have not been able to resolve it yet. So do you mean that I have to add my VM's external IP address as well as *example.com* in CN to create a certificate?

Comment: If you *really* want your browser being able to establish https connections to your IP, then yes. Although arguably, you shouldn't connect to an IP - or if you do, you're testing/troubleshooting, and shouldn't mind a warning.

Comment: Thanks. So do most developers not bother to establishing https connection to their IP and not care about the warning altogether? I won't connect to my IP in production - I just noticed it during testing it and hence asked it.

Comment: Not being familiar with your org: as far as I've seen, never a developer would have an "actual" (trusted) certificate to work with. We may generate self-signed or something out of our own PKI, should a dev actually need to work with ssl/https. Whereas certificates trusted by recognized CAs are only installed on prod/preprod envs, where dev won't have direct access, ...

Comment: Ah I do everything; so change it with whatever term that those coping with the certificate on the actual production environment. So to paraphrase it, do most websites that are in public and production-ready not bother to having the certificate where its CN includes external IP addresses as well as `example.com`?

Comment: As far as I've seen: yes. When you pay for a certificate, you get the name validated, regardless of the IP your service is running behind (likely to change independently from your certificate anyway). Look at google, github, ... Try to connect to one of their IP in https, you'ld end up with the same error.